# How to create a window with DropDownShadow like Sticky Notes in Win 7?

Tags: winapi, dropshadow

How can I create a Win32 window like Sticky Note in Windows 7 which has no border but has drop down shadow effect?

I have tried to create a Win32 window without borders (remove ~WS_BORDER), but the drop down effect shadow is gone.

Any idea?

Best regards,
Zach@Shine

Comment: I know what a "drop-down menu" is, and I am familiar with the "drop shadow". But "drop-down shadow"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the [`CS_DROPSHADOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574%28VS.85%29.aspx) window class (You can apply with `SetClassLongPtr/GCL_STYLE` at runtime iirc)

Comment: If you look carefully, you can find there is a little difference between the shadow by CS_DROPSHADOW and the shadow of Sticky Notes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this in C# WinForms without too much trouble.  You can set the form's border style to none, do some transparency mask tricks for both graphics and hit-tests.

I've done transparency & hit-test masks, and I've done no-border form windows, but I haven't done both together.